# How do I upload my Wordpress code files from previous website onto local host Wordpress website which I created via Xampp?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, xampp, localhost

I have Wordpress code files from an old website which I downloaded from WP File Manager that I want to look at on my local host. I have downloaded Xampp and set up a local host Wordpress website.

How do I now upload the code Wordpress files that I have, in the admin section on my local host, so I can see the front end of the website from the Wordpress code files that I have?

I have tried uploading the files via WP File Manager on the local host version, but it does not work correctly, because it has all the code files from local host website, so it's duplicating.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no native speaker, so errors may be excused.

As it states answer and not solution, i'll try to give some directions.

1. Your question has nothing to do with programming. There are better sites on stackexchange for that.
2. No need for a new WP instance, as you have a copy of the old one. Put it under your \xampp\htdocs\ folder. I imagine WP will need an appropriate .htaccess file as well, if the File Manager didn't get you that too.
3. Get a copy (aka dump) of the database from the old instance. Replace all references to the original url with your localhost adress within the dump.
4. Create a new db on your xampp-setup and import the modified dump into it.
5. edit the wp-config.php if and where necessary
6. Hope and pray it'll run, expect errors and further work